# Scrapy 1.2.0 in Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, dependency-injection, scrapy

Was trying to play with Scrapy for the first time. Switched to my python 3.5 environment created by Anaconda and installed scrapy 1.2.0 per scrapy website:

```
$conda install -c scrapinghub scrapy
```

Now when I try to do

```
$scrapy startproject tutorial
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 6, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/reactor.py", line 38, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import default
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/default.py", line 56, in <module>
    install = _getInstallFunction(platform)
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/default.py", line 50, in _getInstallFunction
    from twisted.internet.selectreactor import install
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py", line 18, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import posixbase
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 18, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import error, udp, tcp
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 28, in <module>
    from twisted.internet._newtls import (
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/_newtls.py", line 21, in <module>
    from twisted.protocols.tls import TLSMemoryBIOFactory, TLSMemoryBIOProtocol
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 41, in <module>
    from OpenSSL.SSL import Error, ZeroReturnError, WantReadError
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 12, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 234, in <module>
    Binding.init_static_locks()
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 180, in init_static_locks
    cls._ensure_ffi_initialized()
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 167, in _ensure_ffi_initialized
    cls.lib = build_conditional_library(lib, CONDITIONAL_NAMES)
  File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 104, in build_conditional_library
    if not getattr(lib, condition):
AttributeError: cffi library '_openssl' has no function, constant or global variable named 'Cryptography_HAS_RSA_OAEP_MD'
```

I looked around the web but no one seems to be having similar issues, could anyone please point me to the right direction? Much obliged!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be related to cryptography and openssl.

[Official documentation page](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux) covers this issue pretty well. Make sure you have all of non-python dependencies.
This is the important bit from the documentation:

> `sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev`

Also there are specific intructions for conda/anaconda installs:

> Because of a bug in conda, attempting to install cryptography out of the box will result in an error. This can be resolved by setting the library path environment variable for your platform.
>
> `env LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/anaconda/lib" pip install cryptography`

Comment: Thank you and that is absolutely spot on. I created a new env for scrapy specifically and reinstalling scrapy fixed the cryptography dependency issue. Thank you again!